# GridView delegates transitions do not work

Tags: animation, gridview, qml, transition

I have following `QML` `GridView`:

```
GridView
{
    id: ueProductGridView

    antialiasing: true

    clip: true

    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Layout.fillHeight: true

    cellWidth: 200
    cellHeight: 200

    delegate: Rectangle
    {
        id: test

        width: 192
        height: 192

        color: "red"

        Text
        {
            anchors.fill: parent

            text: index
        }

        transform:
        [
            Rotation
            {
                id: plateRotation

                angle: -90
                axis { x: 0; y: 1; z: 0 }
                origin.x: -200
                origin.y: 0
            }
        ]   // transform

        SequentialAnimation
        {
            id: addAnimation


            PauseAnimation
            {
                duration: Math.random()*2000
            }

            NumberAnimation
            {
                target: plateRotation
                property: "angle"
                to: 0
                duration: 1000
            }
        }

        SequentialAnimation
        {
            id: removeAnimation


            PropertyAction
            {
                target: test
                property: "GridView.delayRemove"
                value: true
            }

            NumberAnimation
            {
                target: test
                property: "scale"
                to: 0
                duration: 1000
            }

            PropertyAction
            {
                target: test
                property: "GridView.delayRemove"
                value: false
            }
        }

        GridView.onAdd:
        {
            addAnimation.start();
        }   // onAdd

        GridView.onRemove:
        {
            removeAnimation.start();
        }   // onRemove
    }   // delegate

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        model=10;
    }   // onCompleted:
}   // GridView
```

Now, why **`delegate` animations** do not work, i.e., why `GridView` **is empty**? The code regarding animations was taken from [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAhLnJc5iEY) and in there it works. However, if I comment/remove all code regarding animations, `delegate`s are visible in `GridView` and it is all ok:

```
GridView
{
    id: ueProductGridView

    antialiasing: true

    clip: true

    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Layout.fillHeight: true

    cellWidth: 200
    cellHeight: 200

    delegate: Rectangle
    {
        id: test

        width: 192
        height: 192

        color: "red"

        Text
        {
            anchors.fill: parent

            text: index
        }
    }   // delegate

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        model=10;
    }   // onCompleted:
}   // GridView
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animations associated to insertion/removal of elements from the views are `Transition`s (e.g. see [`add`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html#add-prop)), between different `State`s and are indeed called `ViewTransition`s. You should really take a deep look at the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-viewtransition.html) page of this type: it is full of nice examples and describes in great details how addition/removal animations should be implemented.

When you define a `ViewTransition`, any property referenced inside it, if not differently targeted, refer a delegate property. Hence, if you write inside your `GridView`:

```
add: Transition {
    NumberAnimation { property: "opacity"; from: 0; to: 1.0; duration: 500 }
    NumberAnimation { property: "scale"; easing.type: Easing.OutBounce; from: 0; to: 1.0; duration: 750 }
}
```

you are saying that each time a new delegate is added to the grid, its `opacity` as well as `scale` properties should be animated. Top level animations, like in this case, run in parallel so the delegate is scaled and made visible at the same time.

Now, if you want to animate nested properties, like in the case of the `Rotation` angle, *the easiest way* is to `alias` it inside the delegate. That way it can be handled *exactly the same way* as any other delegate property, resulting in a clearer and simpler code.

It should be noted that the animations in your example does not work also because they are associated to `add` `Transition`. Such `Transition` is *not* used during model initialisation when instead the [`populate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html#populate-prop) `Transition` is used. From the documentation:

> This property holds the transition to apply to the items that are initially created for a view.
>
> It is applied to all items that are created when:
>
> The view is first created
>
> The view's model changes
>
> The view's model is reset, if the model is a QAbstractItemModel subclass

Finally, an advice. If you animate addition and removal of elements, especially if the animation is slow, it is also important to animation the  *adjustment* made by the view to the other elements. Animating them in a graceful way can improve visual feeling A LOT. Hence, when you provide a `add` and a `remove` `transition`, take in account also the addition of a [`addDisplaced`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html#addDisplaced-prop) and a [`removeDisplaced`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html#removeDisplaced-prop) `Transition`.

Here follows a modified version of your code that shows all the points discussed above:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: window
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true

    ListModel {
        id: model
         ListElement { code: "0" }
         ListElement { code: "1" }
         ListElement { code: "2" }
         ListElement { code: "3" }
         ListElement { code: "4" }
         ListElement { code: "5" }
    }

    GridView {
        id: ueProductGridView
        anchors.fill: parent
        antialiasing: true

        clip: true
        cellWidth: 200
        cellHeight: 200

        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: 192
            height: 192

            color: "red"
            property alias angle: rot.angle     // alias!
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: code
                font.pixelSize: 30
            }

            transform: Rotation {
                id: rot
                angle: -90
                axis { x: 0; y: 1; z: 0 }
                origin.x: -200
                origin.y: 0
            }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: ueProductGridView.model.remove(index)
            }
        }   // delegate

        add: Transition {
            NumberAnimation { property: "opacity"; from: 0; to: 1.0; duration: 500 }        //since is already at 1.0 we should enforce the start from 0
            NumberAnimation { property: "scale"; easing.type: Easing.OutBounce; from: 0; to: 1.0; duration: 750 }
        }

        addDisplaced: Transition {
            NumberAnimation { properties: "x,y"; duration: 200; easing.type: Easing.InBack }
        }

        remove: Transition {
            NumberAnimation { property: "scale"; from: 1.0; to: 0; duration: 200 }
        }

        removeDisplaced: Transition {
            NumberAnimation { properties: "x,y"; duration: 200; easing.type: Easing.OutBack }
        }

        populate: Transition {
            NumberAnimation { properties: "angle"; to: 0; duration: 500 }
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted:{ ueProductGridView.model= model }
}
```